# Optimizing a Partition Function

Tags: python, optimization, partitioning

Here is the code, in python:

```
# function for pentagonal numbers
def pent (n):     return int((0.5*n)*((3*n)-1))

# function for generalized pentagonal numbers
def gen_pent (n): return pent(int(((-1)**(n+1))*(round((n+1)/2))))

# array for storing partitions - first ten already stored
partitions = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 22, 30, 42]

# function to generate partitions 
def partition (k):
 if (k < len(partitions)): return partitions[k]

 total, sign, i = 0, 1, 1

 while (k - gen_pent(i)) >= 0:
  sign   = (-1)**(int((i-1)/2))
  total += sign*(partition(k - gen_pent(i)))
  i     +=  1

 partitions.insert(k,total)
 return total
```

It uses this method to calculate partitions:

```
p(k) = p(k − 1) + p(k − 2) − p(k  − 5) − p(k − 7) + p(k − 12) + p(k  − 15) ...
```

(source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Generating_function))

However, the code is taking quite some time when it comes to large numbers (over p(10^3)). I want to ask you if I can optimize my code, or hint me to a different but faster algorithm or approach. Any optimization suggestions are welcome.

*And no, before you ask, this is not for homework or Project Euler, its for the experience value.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some comments. Note that I am no expert on this stuff, by I too like messing about with maths (and Project Euler).

I have redefined the pentagonal number functions as follows:

```
def pent_new(n):
    return (n*(3*n - 1))/2

def gen_pent_new(n):
    if n%2:
        i = (n + 1)/2
    else:
        i = -n/2
    return pent_new(i)
```

I have written them in such a way that I don't introduce floating point calculations - for large n using floats will introduce errors (compare the results for `n = 100000001`).

You can use the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) module to test small snippets of code. When I tested all pentagonal functions (yours and mine), the results for mine were quicker. The following is an example which tests your `gen_pent` function.

```
# Add this code to your script
t = Timer("for i in xrange(1, 100): gen_pent(i)", "from __main__ import gen_pent")
print t.timeit()
```

Here is a slight modification of your `partition` function. Again, testing with timeit shows that it is faster than your `partition` function. However, this may be due to the improvements made to the pentagonal number functions.

```
def partition_new(n):
    try:
        return partitions_new[n]
    except IndexError:
        total, sign, i = 0, 1, 1
        k = gen_pent_new(i)
        while n - k >= 0:
            total += sign*partition_new(n - k)

            i += 1
            if i%2: sign *= -1
            k = gen_pent_new(i)

        partitions_new.insert(n, total)
        return total
```

In your partition function, you calculate the general pentagonal number twice for each loop. Once to test in the while condition, and the other to update `total`. I store the result in a variable, so only make the calculation once per loop.

Using the [cProfile](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-profile) module (for python >= 2.5, otherwise the profile module) you can see where your code spends most of its time. Here is an example based on your partition function.

```
import cProfile
import pstats

cProfile.run('partition(70)', 'partition.test')
p = pstats.Stats('partition.test')
p.sort_stats('name')
p.print_stats()
```

This produced the following output in the console window:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ags97128\Desktop>test.py
Fri Jul 02 12:42:15 2010    partition.test

         4652 function calls (4101 primitive calls) in 0.015 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: function name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      552    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       60    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'insert' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.015    0.015 <string>:1(<module>)
     1162    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {round}
     1162    0.006    0.000    0.009    0.000 C:\Documents and Settings\ags97128\Desktop\test.py:11(gen_pent)
    552/1    0.005    0.000    0.015    0.015 C:\Documents and Settings\ags97128\Desktop\test.py:26(partition)
     1162    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 C:\Documents and Settings\ags97128\Desktop\test.py:5(pent)
```

Now profiling my partition function:

```
Fri Jul 02 12:50:10 2010    partition.test

         1836 function calls (1285 primitive calls) in 0.006 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: function name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       60    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'insert' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.006 <string>:1(<module>)
      611    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 C:\Documents and Settings\ags97128\Desktop\test.py:14(gen_pent_new)
    552/1    0.003    0.000    0.006    0.006 C:\Documents and Settings\ags97128\Desktop\test.py:40(partition_new)
      611    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 C:\Documents and Settings\ags97128\Desktop\test.py:8(pent_new)
```

You can see in my results there are no calls to the `len` and `round` builtin functions. And I have nearly halved the number of calls to the pentagonal functions (`gen_pent_new` and `pent_new`)

There are probably other tricks to improving the speed of python code. I would search here for 'python optimization' to see what you can find.

Finally, one of the links at the bottom of the wikipedia page you mentioned is an [academic paper](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~ivan/F49-int-part.pdf) on fast algorithms for calculating partition numbers. A quick glance shows it contains pseudocode for the algorithms. These algorithms will probably be faster than anything you or I could produce.