# Partition Function in Python 2.7 or C++

Tags: python, function, optimization, partition

I spent the entire day to figure out how to solve this problem : [http://www.spoj.com/problems/PARCARD1/]

I took some help from wikipedia : [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28number_theory%29#Partition_function]

and I finally decided to go with this relation :

> p(k) = p(k − 1) + p(k − 2) − p(k − 5) − p(k − 7) + p(k − 12) + p(k − 15) − p(k − 22) − ...

But my implementation is very inefficient...

Python :

```
gpn=[1,2,5,7,12,15,22,26,35,40,51,57,70,77,92,100,117,126,145,155,176,187,210,222,247,260,287,301,330,345,376,392,425,442,477,495,532,551,590,610,651,672,715,737,782,805,852,876,925,950,1001,1027,1080,1107,1162,1190,1247,1276,1335,1365,1426,1457,1520,1552,1617,1650,1717,1751,1820,1855,1926,1962,2035,2072,2147,2185,2262,2301,2380,2420,2501,2542,2625,2667,2752,2795,2882,2926,3015,3060,3151,3197,3290,3337,3432,3480,3577,3626,3725,3775,3876,3927,4030,4082,4187,4240,4347,4401,4510,4565,4676,4732,4845,4902,5017,5075,5192,5251,5370,5430,5551,5612,5735,5797,5922,5985,6112,6176,6305,6370,6501,6567,6700,6767,6902,6970,7107,7176,7315,7385,7526,7597,7740,7812,7957,8030,8177,8251,8400,8475,8626,8702,8855,8932,9087,9165,9322,9401,9560,9640,9801,9882,10045]
t=1001
p=[]
for i in range(1001):
        p.append(0)
p[0]=1
i=1
while i<t:
        k=-1
        j=0
        while (gpn[j]<=i):
            if j%2==0:
                k=k*-1
            #print 'k is : %d' % k
            #print p[i-gpn[j]]
            p[i]=p[i]+k*p[i-gpn[j]]
            j+=1
        print p[i],
        i+=1
```

gpn is generalized pentagonal number

Please help me out....
I read that Hardy-Ramanujan method can be used but is it not an approximation and hence would fail in this case....
Thanks a ton.

Comment: Here's an academic paper on fast methods to calculate partition functions. [Link](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~ivan/F49-int-part.pdf)

Comment: Also, check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164305/optimizing-a-partition-function). Since you only go up to 10^3, this might help. Additionally, you could define `p = [1] + [0]*999`.